# Wordpress ACF Plugin - wp_get_attachment_image function doesn't work with ACF Options Page?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to get an image asset shown on the front-end using the `wp_get_attachment_image` WordPress function, but it doesn't seem to work with my options page on ACF.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

    $image = get_field('logo', 'option');
    $size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)

    if( $image ) {

        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );

    }

?>
```

Which looks like this on the back-end:

[image]

The picture you see above is an options page in ACF and when I try to query that image into the `wp_get_attachment_image` function, it doesn't work. However, when I run this code:

```
<img data-src="<?php the_field('logo', 'option'); ?>" alt="footer logo" class="lazyload" />
```

which is within an image tag, it works just fine.

I copied and pasted what was shows on the ACF docs located [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/) (Basic Display ID), but it's not showing the image on the front-end.

Anything I'm missing guys?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: use wp_get_attachment_image_src with the ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return value in field should be Image ID. See Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What is the return value type you used? Image Array,  Image URL,  Image ID

And you need to get a field like this:
get_field('logo');  why do you add option?

More info here:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/

Answer (score 1):

`wp_get_attachment_image` requires the first parameter to be an image ID. In your case, if you are seeing the image using the code `<img data-src="<?php the_field('logo', 'option'); ?>" alt="footer logo" class="lazyload" />` then `get_field('logo', 'option')` is returning the url of the image.. not the ID which is what you need if you are using `wp_get_attachment_image`.

What you need to do is change the Return Value of your logo field to Image ID.
Then you might have to re upload the image.

And also change this code `<img data-src="<?php the_field('logo', 'option'); ?>" alt="footer logo" class="lazyload" />` to `<img data-src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_field('logo', 'option')); ?>" alt="footer logo" class="lazyload" />`

Answer (score 1):

ACf plugin returns value as you have set the return type.

If you have sent the return type as Image array then :

> $image[0] -> full or $image[0][$full] or $image[$full]   depending on the number of image uploaded.

If you have set return type as Image url:

```
<img src="<?php $image; ?>">  would do the work.
```

If you are setting return type as Image Id:

> $img2 = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($image),
>   $full);   echo $img2[0];

I guess above methods will surely help you out.

Thanks